# SSLCertVerificationError How i can fix?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

i have some problems, when i start my bot in windows then full work, but when i start in macOS 13.5.1 i have error like this

```
during handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/allProjectsPy/multiBots/main.py", line 60, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/allProjectsPy/multiBots/main.py", line 51, in main
    await mbot.get_updates(offset=-1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 412, in get_updates
    return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 354, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py", line 182, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 152, in make_request
    raise TelegramNetworkError(method=method, message=f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)')]
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fa618587df0>
```

my packeges:

```
aiofiles==22.1.0
aiogram==3.0.0b5
aiohttp==3.8.5
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
cryptography==41.0.3
frozenlist==1.4.0
idna==3.4
magic-filter==1.0.11
multidict==6.0.4
peewee==3.16.3
pycparser==2.21
pydantic==1.10.12
pyOpenSSL==23.2.0
typing_extensions==4.7.1
yarl==1.9.2
```

i try this pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
and use only pip install -r requiments

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that you cannot ping the server telegram.org . I solved this problem by disabling ssl verification.
To do this, go to the file **connector.py** , find the **_get_ssl_context** function there. Launch the debug, if verify_ssl is not specified in req, then simply return self._make_ssl_context(True). You will generate an SSL context that will not be verified